# Transforming two queries into one query in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, .net-5

I'm calculating the profit for each `Pair` from `List<BacktestResult>` and the count of its trades, as well as the `BacktestResult` object itself because I need its properties, for ex. to print them. That's what the `foreach` below does. I then want to receive the object of the maximum profit. The code works as expected but I want to recreate it entirely in LINQ, for ex. without that ugly Max() check. It should return `var bestPair = BacktestResult object of the maximum result.Sum(e => e.ProfitPercentage)`.

```cs
(decimal Max, string Pair) value = (int.MinValue, null);
foreach (var result in data.GroupBy(e => e.Pair)
                           .Select(e => new { Pair = e.Key, Count = e.Count(), Value = e }))
{
    var profitSum = result.Value.Sum(e => e.ProfitPercentage);

    if (profitSum > value.Max)
    {
        value.Max = profitSum;
        value.Pair = result.Pair;
    }
}

public class BacktestResult
{
    public string Pair { get; set; }
    public decimal ProfitPercentage { get; set; }
    public decimal ProfitAbs { get; set; }
    public decimal OpenRate { get; set; }
    public decimal CloseRate { get; set; }
    public DateTime OpenDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime CloseDate { get; set; }
    public decimal OpenFee { get; set; }
    public decimal CloseFee { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public decimal TradeDuration { get; set; }
    public SellType SellReason { get; set; }
}

public static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static T MaxBy<T, R>(this IEnumerable<T> en, Func<T, R> evaluate) where R : IComparable<R>
    {
        return en.Select(t => new Tuple<T, R>(t, evaluate(t)))
            .Aggregate((max, next) => next.Item2.CompareTo(max.Item2) > 0 ? next : max).Item1;
    }

    public static T MinBy<T, R>(this IEnumerable<T> en, Func<T, R> evaluate) where R : IComparable<R>
    {
        return en.Select(t => new Tuple<T, R>(t, evaluate(t)))
            .Aggregate((max, next) => next.Item2.CompareTo(max.Item2) < 0 ? next : max).Item1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
string pairOfGroupWithHighestProfitSum = data.GroupBy(e => e.Pair).
Select(e => new { Pair = e.Key, Count = e.Count(), ProfitSum = e.Sum(e => e.ProfitPercentage), Value = e }).
OrderByDescending(e => e.ProfitSum).
FirstOrDefault()?.Pair;
```

If your `data` is empty, it will be null, otherwise you'll get the pair of the group with the highest profit sum.

If you use .NET Core, you won't get performance penalties by first sorting and then taking the first value for finding the max. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/5.0/orderby-firstordefault-complexity-increase

Comment: I'm using .NET 5.

Comment: ProfitPercentage is not accessible from OrderByDescending. Even though I tried `e.Value.ProfitPercentage`, it still isn't because it's `IGrouping<string, BacktestResult>`.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. It should be `OrderByDescending(e => e.ProfitSum)`

Comment: Thank you very much! It looks much better rn